# Condition on functions satisfying certain inequality

Tags: functions, functional-inequalities

I came across the following problem:

Given two functions u,v mapping $[0.5,1]\to (0,1]$ where u(x) is the identity function, $u(x)=x$. Suppose that $\frac{u(x)}{u(1-x)}> \frac{v(x)}{v(1-x)}$ holds. What can we say about the function $v(x)$?

Candidates I was thinking about are concave, log-concave, or other conditions on the derivative.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: What does the arrow mean here?

Comment: I am sorry, that was a typo. I meant to write $>$.